# Named <slot> elements can't receive <template> elements

Tags: polymer

I have a little problem with the `<slot/>` element.

From Polymer version >= 1.8 `<slot/>` elements should be used, instead of `<content/>`, for creating insertion points. But a `<slot/>` cannot receive a `<template/>` element in any way, when it has a name.

When I create an unnamed (default) slot in my container element:

```
<dom-module id="my-container">
    <template>

        <slot id="defaultSlot"></slot>

    </template>
</dom-module>
```

and nest a plain template:

```
<my-container id="container">

    <template>
      <div>foo</div>
    </template>

</my-container>
```

it works perfectly, which can be verified using:

`> container.$.defaultSlot.getDistributedNodes().length↵ -> 1`

However, slotting of template elements stops working as soon as I give that slot a name:

```
<dom-module id="my-container">
    <template>

        <slot name="bar" id="namedSlot"></slot>

    </template>
</dom-module>


<my-container id="container">

    <template slot="bar">
        <div>foo</div>
    </template>

</my-container>
```

`> container.$.namedSlot.getDistributedNodes().length↵ -> 0`

What i really need is to make `<slot/>` somehow accept any `<template/>` by slot name.

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2va41sy0/).